# Add an array to a json object in extjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, extjs

I wish to have an attribute called idField in my json object. Now this attribute is either an array if it contains multiple elements or just an object if it contains one element. I wish to create such an attribute from the data in an extjs store. In essence if the store contains just one element I need to insert this idField 'object' in the json object otherwise I need to insert an 'array' called idField in the json object. Please advise as to how to do that.

**EDIT:**

My store has 2 columns namely 'name' and 'type' in its data. What I wish is that if it contains just one element then my object should look like this:

```
{
    ...
    idField : {
        name : ...
        type : ...
    }
}
```

If my store contains 2 rows then my object should look like this :

```
{
    ...
    idField : [
    {
        name : ...
        type : ...
    },
    {
        name : ...
        type : ...
    }
    ]
}
```

Also I have to INSERT this idField attribute inside the object. There is no currect idField attribute yet in the object.

**EDIT 2:**

I received this object in the console when I wrote `console.log(Ext.getStore("My_store_name").data)`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data from the EXT JS store

```
var data = Ext.getStore("Your_Store_Name").data
```

In my snippet below I am assuming that you like to get the values from field name called item.

```
var data = Ext.getStore("Your_Store_Name").data 
//imagine your JSON where you need to store is in variable myJSON 
if (data.items.length == 1){ 
myJSON.idField = {type: 'sometype', name: data.item[0]} } 
else if (data.item.length > 1)
{ //make an array of JSON 
var list = []; 
for(var i = 0; i < data.item.length; i++)
{  
list.push({type: 'sometype', name: data.item[i]})
} 
myJSON.idField = list; //set the array
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I have updated the post. Your approach won't work for my case since I don't have any idField attribute inside the object yet. I need to insert either an object or an array according to the number of elements in the store

Comment: OK, can you go to your browser console this 
Ext.getStore("Your_Store_Name").data
can you paste a snippet of that.

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of the object I received in the console

Comment: var data = Ext.getStore("Your_Store_Name").data

//imagine your JSON where you need to store is in variable myJSON

if (data.items.length == 1){

myJSON.idField = {type: 'sometype', name: data.item[0]}

} else if (data.item.length > 1){

//make an array of JSON
var list = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.item.length; i++){
      list.push({type: 'sometype', name: data.item[i]})
}
myJSON.idField = list;

}

Comment: Can you please update your answer itself because its a bit unclear in the comments. This way if it works I can chose it as the official answer as well for others to see.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried your approach and my issue stands resolved. Just one follow up. If I have just one row in my store, how do I access that row's 2 columns? For inserting as an object data.item[0] is undefined. I need to access that one row's name and type values

Comment: Ok if you have one row in your store that means the "items" array will be having single json.
Can you paste the single JSON in item.
Or can you please show me the JSON snippet and what you want to achieve that would be helpful.

Comment: I was able to access it via Ext.getStore("storename").getAt(0).data.name. Thanks for all your help. It helped me solve a very critical issue :)